# Regarding creating React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am learning React and ES6. In the process of learning, I stumbled upon a code snippet which I have mentioned below.

```
import { getBoxStyle } from './PythagorasTree.js'

export const TreeBox = (props) => {
  const style = getBoxStyle(props)
  const baseProps = Object.assign({}, props, {
    level: props.level + 1,
  })
 // What this function does 
  const leftChild =
    props.level < props.totalLevels &&
    React.createElement(TreeBox,
      Object.assign({}, baseProps, { right: false })
    )
  const rightChild =
    props.level < props.totalLevels &&
    React.createElement(TreeBox,
      Object.assign({}, baseProps, { right: true })
    )

  return React.createElement('div', { style },
    leftChild,
    rightChild
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(TreeBox, {
    level: 0,
    totalLevels: 5,
    heightFactor: 0.37,
    lean: -0.10,
    size: 100,
  }),
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

My question here is what does variable do in below piece of code

```
// What this function does 
  const leftChild =
    props.level < props.totalLevels &&
    React.createElement(TreeBox,
      Object.assign({}, baseProps, { right: false })
    )
```

According to the code, it should return some TreeBox components to the DOM but i didn't understand if there is a loop or recursive method in that. I can see the comparison but I can't able to find any recursion or looping in that.

```
var i = 10;
var j = 5;
var test = function(){ j++; console.log('Hello'); } 
var hello = j < i && test();
```

Is it correct way to interpret? It is not printing recursively. How do I interpret that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `props.level` is less than `props.totalLevels` then Create and return a new React element of the given type. The type argument can be either a tag name string (such as 'div' or 'span'), a React component type (a class or a function), or a React fragment type.

ex:

```
React.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

`&&` just means if what comes before is true then execute what comes after.

Comment: Is it specific to React or applied to all ES6?? because i tried something like                                                                                    
                                                                                                          
    var i = 10;
    var j = 5;

    var test = function(){ 
        j++;
     console.log('Hello');
    }
    var hello = j < i && test();

console.log(hello); 
This printing the hello just for one time.

Comment: kind of hard to understand what your asking.

Comment: I have updated the question please have a look at it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: `var hello = j < i && test(); console.log(hello);` hello will contain the logic when you console log it so it will be in the console `j < i && test();`